# (Socket/Networking) Is it possible to reconnect a Socket or my own Raw Socket?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking, raw-sockets

I've been challenging myself to code an way to connect() back a socket after it has disconnected (For experimental tests).

If i consider that an negative file descriptor will be assigned on the socket after a close() call i know i cannot close the socket

Plus i can not connect() back (in the formal and common way) because after RST or last FIN ACK the socket will join Closed State + time_wait
TIME_WAIT is not a trouble but Closed State is the issue.

*Assigning a new file descriptor (either with low level access by C++ or even Java Injection or Kernel Modify ) is not a way of, since my point is to re-use the same file-descriptor.*

**Could anyone tell me if it is possible to do it ? Any possibility?**
**Or if it is possible to not join any "unconnectable state" by using raw sockets?**

Comment: Can you provide the code that disconnects a connected socket, and then the attempt to reconnect?

Comment: Its an common code in C++, i just debugged and got the socket to be in a given state called "closed", i've searched about it and it happens automatically and is done by the kernel, so basically you can reproduce it by using a normal socket commonly

Comment: No, it's not possible to reconnect a socket. You have to create a new socket and make a new connection.

Comment: Even if you could do something to revive the connection what then? At the other end of the socket there was a programming listening and it has already seen your end of the socket being closed and it has closed its end of the connection so there is nothing listening on the other end for you to communicate with anymore.

Comment: @MartinYork I think the OP had the thought that the `shutdown()` API was meant to allow a socket to be used again. For a new connection.

Comment: @jxh Yes and im actually trying to modify the socket state to the same as it was when it got created.
According to linux and man() docs the end peer will detach my socket right after an RST or the last FIN ACK. So server will be able to re-accept my connection as far as im able to re-connect, my question was directly for how is it possible to reconnect a socket by changing its State according to the description i gave... as well without creating a new socket and not even changing file descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the OS will treat the plain socket used to establish a connection as already connected, even after it transitions to the closed state.

A workaround to using the same file descriptor is to create a new socket, and then use `dup2()` to allow the new socket to adopt the original file descriptor. You then close the file descriptor that had been created for the new socket.

```
int renew_socket (int s) {
    int new_s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (new_s < 0 || s < 0) return new_s;

    dup2(new_s, s);
    close(new_s);
    return s;
}
```